# Draw a line to a texture Open GL ES 2.0 Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a simple question for you here. I am using a texture to render a bitmap to and everything appears fine. However I would like to draw a line on top of said texture. I know how vert/tex coordinates work but I am unable to achieve this for some unknown reason. I am making my call to draw my line after the call to draw the bitmap to the texture but only the bitmap shows still. What is the best way to achieve this? I am using texure2D to draw the bitmap in my fragment shader, does something need to be added to this to draw the line with a specified color? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Code Relevant to bitmap texturing:

```
 private final String vertexTextureShaderCode =
                "attribute vec4 aPosition;"+ // Position of out Vertex
                "attribute vec2 aTexPosition;"+ // Position of our texture contained in the vertex
                "varying vec2 vTexPosition;"+ //
                "void main(){"+
                "    gl_Position = aPosition;"+
                "    vTexPosition = aTexPosition;"+
                "}";


private final String fragmentTextureShaderCode =
                "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform sampler2D uTexture;" + // Our Background Image  ( Our uploaded image)
                "varying vec2 vTexPosition;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTexPosition);" +
                "}";

public void draw(float[] m ,ImageEffectFactory effectFactory,int currentEffect){
    // add program to OpenGl ES Environment;
    this.imageEffectFactory = effectFactory;
    boolean effectChanged = false;
    if(currentEffect != mCurrentEffect){
        mCurrentEffect = currentEffect;
        effectChanged = true;
    }

    int whichTexture = 0;
    if(currentEffect > 0 && currentEffect < 6){
        whichTexture = 1;
        if(effectChanged) {
            imageEffectFactory.applyEffect(mTexturePointer, ImageEffectFactory.FILTER.values()[currentEffect], mTextureImageWidth, mTextureImageHeight);
            effectChanged = false;
        }
    }

    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    GLES20.glViewport(0,0,mViewWidth, mViewHeight);

    // get handle to vertex shader vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
    mTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uTexture");
    mTexturePositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTexPosition");


    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTexturePositionHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mTextureBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTexturePositionHandle);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexturePointer[whichTexture]);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureHandle,0);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexBuffer);

    // enable a handle to the triangle vertice
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);


    // Draw the square
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertexCount);

    // Disbale the vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);


}
```

As I have mentioned, this works fine. the bitmap I am attempting to load will show up and look perfect. But after this is drawn I attempt to draw the line. Here is the setup for the line :

```
private static final String vsShader =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;"+
        "attribute vec4 vPosition; " +
        "void main() { " +
        "   gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
        " }";

private static final String fsShader =
        "precision mediump float;"
        + "uniform vec4 vColor;"
        + "void main() {"
        + "gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
        "}";

 private float[] pathCoords = {
        -0.5f, 0.5f,0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f
};


private short[] pathDrawOrder = {0,1};
    private float[] color = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}; //  - red for testing
    private final FloatBuffer mVertBuffer;
private final ShortBuffer mDrawListBuffer;


private int mCropProgram;

private int vPositionHandle;
private int vColorHandle;
private int uMVPMatrixHandle;

public CropFrameRect(Context context){
    this.context = context;

    // Allocat a byteBuffer for our Vertex Array;
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pathCoords.length * 4);

    // ORder those Bytes correctly depending on the device (ie. BIG-ENDIAN vs. LITTLE-ENDIAN
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    // Lets now store those vertex points into a FloatBuffer please.
    mVertBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    mVertBuffer.put(pathCoords);
    mVertBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pathDrawOrder.length*2);
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    mDrawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    mDrawListBuffer.put(pathDrawOrder);
    mDrawListBuffer.position(0);

    int vertexShader = ImageGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vsShader);

    int fragmentShader = ImageGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fsShader);

    // We've compiled our vertex and our texture shader programs. Let us create the program..
    mCropProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

    // Attach the vertex shader string
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mCropProgram, vertexShader);

    // Attach the shader program string
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mCropProgram, fragmentShader);

    // Link the program code to the OpenGL Context
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mCropProgram);

    Log.d(TAG, "Crop Program Linked: " + mCropProgram);
}

public void draw(float[] matrix){
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mCropProgram);



    vPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mCropProgram, "vPosition");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mVertBuffer);

    // set the color
    vColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mCropProgram, "vColor");
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(vColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

    // set the Matrix projection for the View;
    uMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mCropProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(uMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, matrix, 0);

    GLES20.glLineWidth(2.7f);


    // Draw those elements
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_LINES, pathDrawOrder.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mDrawListBuffer);

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(vPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisable(vColorHandle);

}
```

Comment: Where and what is the mDrawListBuffer, same for pathDrawOrder; Is mCropProgram valid and corresponds to the sources in fsShader and vsShader? Are the handles valid (vPositionHandle) as is the value none-negative? What are matrix values?

Comment: the mDrawListBuffer is the shortBuffer that I store my draw order list in. I dont think this is needed probably but I also didnt think it could hurt. I added more code to this sample. The mCropProgram is valid and is corresponding to fsShader and vsShader, I am 99% certain of that. I apologize for this not being more complete the first time. I will update my matrix values shortly Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all some code on what you are doing might prove useful. If the texture shows correctly I could only guess there is something wrong with drawing the line. But there are many reasons for the failure of the drawing.

Second the question title is "how to draw a line to a texture" while the description seems to be asking how to draw a line over the drawn texture. Note these 2 are very different as drawing to a texture is quite common.

So if you have successfully drawn the texture to your view but you fail to draw the line over it then I guess it is best to start debugging the issue. You should start by trying to draw the line without the texture and see if it draws. 
If it does not:

- Check if coordinates make sense
- Check if matrices make sense or even disable them (use identity) for the debugging
- Check your shader for drawing the lines as you would most likely need a separate shader to draw a solid color instead of the texture
- Check if line width is set
- If all fails then create a new shader that output a hardcoded solid color (white for instance) and excepts nothing but positions, create vertices `(0,0), (1,1)` and draw them as a line. Nothing else should be drawn and no calls but clearing the buffer should be done to openGL. After this is working you can start building upwards from this and see where your mistake is.

If it does draw directly from removing the call to draw the texture then my best guess would be you have a depth test enabled and the line is behind the texture. Try disabling the depth test or try to bring the line a bit closer.

Comment: Thank you for the response and the information. I have updated my question with what should be relevant pieces of code. There must be a disconnect here. I am sure I am making some stupid mistake, but hey thats just the way learning goes sometimes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: A lot of code there makes very little sense. Do you check for errors as some lines would most likely produce it. So just looking at the second part (the line): The part with the texture should not be there, the texture handle does not even correspond to this shader. GLES20.glDisable(vColorHandle) is a NO-NO. You clear the buffer in the beginning so if you were drawing the texture before that it should not be visible at all...

Comment: The texture handle was a mistake on my end. A remnant of past trials and errors. i have updated the sample to reflect what I am currently using without success.

Answer (score 0):

You must change fragmentTextureShaderCode for this code.

```
private final String fragmentTextureShaderCode =
                "precision mediump float;" +
                "vec2 u_line_prop" + //line slope and bias 
                "uniform vec2 u_resolution;" + //width, height GlSurfaceTexture
                "uniform sampler2D uTexture;" + // Our Background Image  ( Our uploaded image)
                "varying vec2 vTexPosition;" +
// Plot a line on Y using a value between 0.0-1.0
                "float plotLine(vec2 st, float pct){" +
                "  return  smoothstep( pct-0.02, pct, st.y) -" +
                "  smoothstep( pct, pct+0.02, st.y);" +
                "}" +


                "void main() {" +
                "  vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;" +
                "  st.x *= u_resolution.x/u_resolution.y;" +
                //line formula
                "  float y = st.x*u_line_prop.x+u_line_prop.y;" +
                "  float pct = plotLine(st,y);" +    
                "  colorLine = texture2D(uTexture, vTexPosition);" +
                "  vec4 colorLine = vec4 (1.0,1.0, 0.0,1.0) ;" +
                "  gl_FragColor = mix(colorTexture, colorLine, pct);"  
                "}";
```

Then you must correct your java code to transfer two additional vectors:

- u_line_prop //line slope and bias
- u_resolution //width, height GlSurfaceTexture
  *Shader program for the line is not needed!*

You can check how the similar code works in the online [Shaders editor](http://thebookofshaders.com/edit.php?log=180317180942)